# R - k-fold cross-validation for linear regression with standard error of estimate

Tags: r, linear-regression, cross-validation, r-caret, standard-error

I would like to perform k-fold cross-validation in R for a linear regression model and test the one standard error rule:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17904/one-standard-error-rule-for-variable-selection

Thus, I need a function which gives me back the cross-validation estimate of the prediction error **and** the standard error of this estimate (or at least the MSE for each fold, so that I can compute the standard error myself). Many packages have functions which compute the cross-validation error (for example, `cv.glm` in the `boost` package), but usually they return only the CV estimate of the prediction error and not its standard error, or the MSE for each fold.

I tried using package `DAAG`, whose function `CVlm` should give a richer output than `cv.glm`. However, I can't seem to make it work! Here is my code:

```
a=c(0.0056, 0.0088, 0.0148, 0.0247, 0.0392, 0.0556, 0.0632, 0.0686, 0.0786, 0.0855, 0.0937)
b=c(6.0813, 9.5011, 15.5194, 23.9409, 32.8492, 40.8399, 43.8760, 45.5270, 46.7668, 46.1587, 43.4524)
dataset=data.frame(x=a,y=b)
CV.list=CVlm(df=dataset,form.lm = formula(y ~ poly(x,2)), m=5)
```

I get the hardly informative error

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

which doesn't make much sense to me. `x` and `y` are the same length (11), so  clearly the function is complaining about some other `x`,`y` variables it created internally.

I'd gladly accept solutions with other packages (for example `caret`). Also, it would be great if I could specify a number of repetitions for the k-fold cross-validation.

Comment: `caret`'s `train` function isn't designed to do that.

Comment: @topepo, wow! You're the owner of the github repository for `caret`, aren't you? Then there's no hope for me to solve this by turning to `caret`. What a pity! Do you know of any other packages which may help me implement the one SE rule? BTW, do you have any suggestions about the error `DAAG`'s `CVlm` is throwing?

Comment: nobody? not even to help me understand why the `DAAG` code is not working? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CVlm` doesn't like the `poly(x,2)` in your formula. You can easily circumvent that by adding the result of `poly(x,2)` first in your datatable and calling `CVlm` on these new variables:

```
dataset2 <- cbind(dataset,poly(dataset$x,2))
names(dataset2)[3:4] <- c("p1","p2")
CV.list=CVlm(df=dataset2,form.lm = formula(y ~ p1+p2))
```

And as you are interested by the values printed that are unfortunately not saved anywhere you can use something like:

```
# captures the printed output
printOut <- capture.output(CV.list=CVlm(df=dataset2,form.lm = formula(y ~ p1+p2)))

# function to parse the output 
# to be adapted if necessary for your needs
GetValues <- function(itemName,printOut){
    line <- printOut[grep(itemName,printOut)]
    items <- unlist(strsplit(line,"[=]|  +"))
    itemsMat <- matrix(items,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
    vectVals <- as.numeric(itemsMat[grep(itemName,itemsMat[,1]),2])
    return(vectVals)
}

# get the Mean square values as a vector
MS <- GetValues("Mean square",printOut)
```

Comment: Thanks! That nailed it. I see CVlm prints to screen the MSE for each fold, which I was looking for. But it literally only prints it to screen! It doesn't return it as a vector. Do you know how could I store it in a variable? Other than my current "brutish" scroll-the-screen-up-and-down-copy-each-value-create-a-vector.

Comment: @DeltaIV Check it out now

Answer (score 1):

The average MSE is stored as an attribute to the model object. 
`attributes(CV.list)$ms` gives you what you're looking for.